# No errors appear in Visual Studio or VSCode using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, syntax-error

[Image of my code in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RdRn.png)

Forgive me, I am somewhat new to coding, so maybe this is a dumb question.

I am learning how to use Unity and I am using Visual Studio to edit my code (C#).
For some reason, the red squiggly lines will not appear for most errors. It won't even recognize that there is an error.

The only error I have had it recognize is a missing semicolon.

For example, I can say a string is equal to a float (as seen below: characterName = itemDurability;), and it had not issue with this in either Visual Studio or VSCode. I can have an item defined as multiple different things, and still no errors. Of course Unity will tell me there is a problem when the code loads, but I'd like to know as I'm writing it.

I have tried updating and reinstalling, but nothing works. I cannot find anything online that has helped me with this problem.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
  {
    string characterName;

    characterName = "Duncan";

    int characterLevel = 5;
    int experience = characterLevel * 5;

    float itemDurability = 1.527f;

    experience = (int)itemDurability;

    characterName = itemDurability; 

            bool equippable = false;
    if (itemDurability > 1f)
    {
        experience = (int)(itemDurability * 1.5f) / characterLevel;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you're talking about, and the errors you expect.  This is too vague.

Comment: Could be that the code file is not set to compile in the project properties but was added as content. Hard to say with out any additional information though.

Comment: @Igor They say a missing semicolon is detected as an error, which suggests to me the file is set to compile.

Comment: Okay, and what errors are you expecting to be raised by the compiler in this code?

Comment: itemDurability is a float, but then you try to convert it to an int and a string.  What's up with that?  What does characterName have to do with itemDurability?

Comment: I'm getting CS0029 "Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'string'" on that line.

Comment: I am taking a course on how to learn Unity and following along with a video. In the video, his code produces an error, but mine does not. This code is not meant to do anything, I am simply trying to understand why it will not give me errors.

Comment: Something is wrong with your project, but I can't say what.  I can confirm that this code should be raising a compiler error though.

Comment: @DuncanMoseley, can you confirm if the below post answered your query, if not I'd be happy to help further

Comment: @Clint, actually I had a different problem.  I eventually realized that Visual Studio was not properly importing or recognizing all the information it needed from Unity, so that was somehow making it not detect any errors. Thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 0):

From your screen-shot, it appears that you have opened the `.cs` (using VS) by double clicking on it or that file is not part(or excluded) of your Project , essentially you're opening the file for editing and using VS like a text editor as Indicated by `Miscellaneous Files`and `Attach Debugger` symbol from your snap

Ensure that File is added to your `Project` with `SolutionExplorer` window and `BuildAction=C# Compiler`. See [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtbnE.png)

> The only error I have had it recognize is a missing semicolon.

*Visual Studio IDE interpreted the file as C# from the .cs extensions, and because of which it will look for `;` and a semicolon is required at the end of every *statement* in C#.*

> For some reason, the red squiggly lines will not appear for most errors

*Compiler is only doing a syntax check and not checking the semantics of the statements, for that matter compiler will even accept something like
`Myclass a = new MyClass();` even though `MyClass` is not defined*